# Xcode 9.3.1 Unknown class in Interface Builder File

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been trying to make an onboarding screen for my iOS game made using Sprite Kit. I am using the ramotion kit(https://github.com/Ramotion/paper-onboarding) for doing the same. I keep getting this error, Unknown class in interface builder and I have been stuck on this for ages. Here is my code for the GameViewController class:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import PaperOnboarding

protocol Controller {
    func levelCompleted()
    func levelFailed()
}

/* GameViewController is in charge of managing the game. This includes creating and
 * changing levels, access to main menu, etc.
 */
var count = 0
class GameViewController: UIViewController, PaperOnboardingDataSource, PaperOnboardingDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet var onboardingView: OnboardingView!
    @IBOutlet var getStartedButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "actualGame")
        initialiseSKScene()
    }

    var currentLevel: Level? = nil
    var config: GameConfiguration?
    var skView: SKView?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        onboardingView.dataSource = self
        onboardingView.delegate = self
    }

    func initialiseSKScene()
    {
        let skView = initialiseSKView()
        do
        {
            config = try GameConfiguration(file: "level_json_sample", size: skView.bounds.size)
        }
        catch let error
        {
            print("Level cannot be loaded!")
            print(error)
        }

        let teethArray = config!.getTeethByLevel(id: 1)
        let objectArray = config!.getObjectsByLevel(id: 1)
        print(objectArray[0])

        // Use the JSON file to open level 1

        currentLevel = Level(size: skView.bounds.size, bgFile: "background2.png",
                             teethArray: teethArray, otherArray: objectArray, c: self as! Controller)

        currentLevel?.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.resizeFill

        skView.presentScene(currentLevel)
    }

    func onboardingItemsCount() -> Int
    {
        return 3
    }

    func onboardingItem(at index: Int) -> OnboardingItemInfo
    {

        let onBoardItem1 = OnboardingItemInfo(informationImage: UIImage(named: "rocket")!,
                                              title: "A Great Rocket Start",
                                              description: "Caramels cheesecake bonbon bonbon topping. Candy halvah cotton candy chocolate bar cake. Fruitcake liquorice candy canes marshmallow topping powder.",
                                              pageIcon: UIImage(named: "rocket")!,
                                              color: UIColor(red: 217/255, green: 72/255, blue: 89/255, alpha: 1),
                                              titleColor: UIColor.white,
                                              descriptionColor: UIColor.white,
                                              titleFont: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 24)!,
                                              descriptionFont: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 18)!)

        let onBoardItem2 = OnboardingItemInfo(informationImage: UIImage(named: "brush")!,
                                              title: "Design your Experience",
                                              description: "Caramels cheesecake bonbon bonbon topping. Candy halvah cotton candy chocolate bar cake. Fruitcake liquorice candy canes marshmallow topping powder.",
                                              pageIcon: UIImage(named: "brush")!,
                                              color: UIColor(red: 106/255, green: 166/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1),
                                              titleColor: UIColor.white,
                                              descriptionColor: UIColor.white,
                                              titleFont: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 24)!,
                                              descriptionFont: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 18)!)

        let onBoardItem3 = OnboardingItemInfo(informationImage: UIImage(named: "notification")!,
                                              title: "Stay Up To Date",
                                              description: "Get notified of important updates.",
                                              pageIcon: UIImage(named: "notification")!,
                                              color: UIColor(red: 168/255, green: 200/255, blue: 78/255, alpha: 1),
                                              titleColor: UIColor.white,
                                              descriptionColor: UIColor.white,
                                              titleFont: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 24)!,
                                              descriptionFont: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 18)!)

        return [onBoardItem1,onBoardItem2,onBoardItem3][index]

    }

    /* Initialises the SKView where we display the game */
    private func initialiseSKView() -> SKView
    {
        let skView =  self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsPhysics = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        skView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
        return skView
    }

    /* This method is called by the currentLevel when it is completed */
    func levelCompleted() {
        // check if there exists a higher level than currentLevel.id
        // change to next level or present winning screen
        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
        let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: skView!.bounds.size, won: false)
        skView?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
    }

    func onboardingConfigurationItem(_: OnboardingContentViewItem, index _: Int)
    {

    }

    func onboardingWillTransitonToIndex(_ index: Int)
    {
        if index == 1
        {
            if self.getStartedButton.alpha == 1
            {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations:
                {
                        self.getStartedButton.alpha = 0
                })
            }
        }
    }

    func onboardingDidTransitonToIndex(_ index: Int)
    {
        if index == 2
        {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations:
            {
                self.getStartedButton.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }

    /* This method is called by the currentLevel when it is failed */
    func levelFailed() {
        // present losing screen
        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
        let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: skView!.bounds.size, won: false)
        skView?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
    }

}
```

I get the Unknown class in interface builder error and this line in ViewDidLoad() shows:
"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
onboardingView.dataSource = self
```

I have checked all my outlets and classes in interface builder as well and all of them are proper!
Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Try Connecting the outlet once again.

Comment: No success. Now I'm getting "Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x10c52bfd8) to 'SKView' (0x10af21480)" with a SIGABRT error at "let skView =  view as! SKView" which is the first line in the initialiseSKView() function. Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you have SKView on your xib.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @TalCohen. Can you please instruct how that can be done in correlation to the code?